# hibernate mapping of single column to multiple properties

Tags: hibernate

I need to map a database field of type into two properties so that property = field value mod 100 and property2 = field value % 100, how is that done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straghtforwad way would be to define a getter for %100 variant returning just %100 of mapped property in question. ( And maybe respective setter if you like it to be settable )  -  so no need to hack hibernate.